# Grouping logs that occurred on the same day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some log objects that have a date assigned to them. In the view I am showing them by doing

```
<% @time_logs.each do |timelog| %>
```

I want to make it so that if there were multiple logs, they are displayed as one log without having to combine them and store them somewhere else. Example

Before

```
Date: 10/05/11   Something: 2    Something else: 3
Date: 10/05/11   Something: 3    Something else: 4
```

After

```
Date: 10/05/11   Something: 5    Something else: 7
```

Would I do this in the model, controller, view? Do I have to make a new controller? And what is the best way of doing this without having to alter the data or save it in another database and pull from that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for your database. With a combination of `SUM` and `GROUP BY` you don't have to mess with your application code.

`ActiveRecord` has methods to do this, see `sum` and `group`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

**Updated**

This answer [Multiple sum()s in ActiveRecord in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656907/multiple-sums-in-activerecord-in-rails) have some great code you can start with using `group` and `sum`.

Comment: Ok, this sounds simple enough. Would you be able to expand a little more or maybe give me a starting point? I'm using mysql if that helps and I'm a bit lost on how active record querying is working in my context.